# Using the particle と instead of the particle で

Tags: particles, particle-と, particle-で

Can I say 家族と　instead of 家族で　in the sentence below?

> 今年の夏、私は**家族で**山の中にあるホテルに泊まりました。

If I can, how does the meaning of the sentence change if I use the different particle?

Another example:

> **兄弟で**遊びます。

Again, I wonder if で　and と　are interchangeable here.